Dummy proof of going down theorem
I have written a proof of the Going-down theorem that doesn't use the assumption that the smaller ring in the integral extension is normal, so it's false but I can't find the mistake. Can you tell where it's wrong?
Going down theorem follows easily from the following statement:
(I) Let A, B be commutative integral domains, $\ \omega: A \rightarrow B$ is injective homomorphism, which is integral (which means $B$ is integral extension of $\omega(A)$), $\ q \in Spec(B)$, $\ p = \omega^{-1}(q)$, $\ S = B - q$, $\ \lambda$ is the localization homomorphism for $S$ in $B$, $\ \lambda_\omega$ is the localization homomorphism for $\omega^{-1}(S)$ in $A$, $\ S^{-1}\omega$ is the induced map in the following diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A @>\omega >> B\\
@VV\lambda_\omega V @VV\lambda V\\
(\omega^{-1}S)^{-1}A @>S^{-1}\omega >> S^{-1}B
\end{CD}
then the induced map
$$
(S^{-1} \omega)^*: Spec(S^{-1}B) \rightarrow Spec((\omega^{-1}S)^{-1}A) \\
(S^{-1} \omega)^*(J) = (S^{-1} \omega)^{-1}(J)
$$
is surjective. ($S^{-1} \omega$ is well-defined because of universal property of localization)
So I'll prove (with error which I wasn't able to find) statement (I):
Consider the following commutative diagram:
\begin{CD}
Spec(A, \omega^{-1}S) @<\omega^*|_{Spec(B, S)} << Spec(B, S) \\
@AA\lambda_\omega^* A    @AA\lambda^* A \\
Spec((\omega^{-1}S)^{-1} A) @<(S^{-1} \omega)^* << Spec(S^{-1}B)
\end{CD}
where upper star for a map gives the induced map on spectrums, e.g. for a map $\theta: E \rightarrow F$ it gives the induced map
$$
\theta^*: Spec(F) \rightarrow Spec(E) \\
\theta^*(J) = \theta^{-1}(J)
$$
and $Spec(M, N)$, where $N$ is a subset of $M$, is the set of all prime ideals of $M$ which don't intersect with $N$
It's well known that $\lambda^*$ and $\lambda_\omega^*$ are bijective and $\omega^*$ is surjective (since $\omega$ is integral and A, B are integral domains), so $\omega^*|_{Spec(B, S)}$ is also surjective.
So we can conclude that $(S^{-1} \omega)^* = (\lambda_\omega^*)^{-1} \circ \omega^*|_{Spec(B, S)} \circ \lambda^*$ is also surjective, since all maps from the right hand side are surjective.
To prove Going down theorem simply consider localization of $B$ with respect to $q$, then since induced map $S^{-1}\omega^*$ is surjective there exist $q' \in Spec(B_q)$ such that $(S^{-1}\omega)^{-1}(q') = p' \subset (\omega^{-1}S)^{-1}p$, then the result follows from the fact, that $\lambda^*, \lambda_\omega^*$ are bijections.
Q.E.D.
So I haven't used that $A$ is normal. I spent quite a few time, but haven't found a mistake.

Why is the restriction of $\omega^*$ surjective?

Someone(sorry, I haven't remembered the name) answered my question in the past, but later he deleted his comment, so I'll add the answer.
The problem is that $\omega^*|_{Spec(B,S)}$ may be not surjective.
